# Is there any icon to represent media roughly?

Tags: icon, designers, graphic-styles, reference-request

I'll try to explain what I mean by media here.

Media has some definitions in dictionaries. What I'm talking about can be explained by following examples (source: Online dictionaries):

> There was a tremendous amount of media coverage of the funeral of
> Princess Diana.
>
> Media was accused of influencing final decision
>
> My original statement has been completely distorted by the media.

And my own example is: Let's say someone died because of murder and someone is accused of it. But he actually didn't kill him (nobody knows it). But news channels, to gain attention, show *intriguing/attractive* (don't know which words to use here to explain) news so that people take interest in it.

Or it can be opposite too. The accused is proved guilty and same news channels are showing news again and again for the same *attraction*.

Also, examples I'm giving seems too harsh and negative. But I don't mean that it should be this way only. It can be any normal stuff, any positive stuff etc.

So I guess media is somewhat: News Channels + Their reporters + Cameraman + (Newspapers maybe?) etc.

Given all that, is there any icon (or combination of some icons) that can roughly represent this **media** word?

One more example I've found and often seen on Facebook (I didn't edit anything in it):

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112756/discussion-on-question-by-vikas-is-there-any-icon-to-represent-media-roughly).

Comment: Also words you're using are a bit hard for me to understand.

Comment: I always seem to find this topic kind of frustrating when the expectation is that the icon should represent like a whole brochure worth of information. I'm not against exploring that and seeing what can be used, but generally speaking, it's not worth it to try and force it. Icons should be simple. It could be anything that your user can associate with the content... It could be just a red circle. If we look at something like the "coming soon" icon in netflix's mobile app, it's just 2 boxes, one on top of the other and the top one has a play icon.

Comment: Without the text you could just about make the connection that it has some kind of video content, but not that they are coming soon. The icon for "games" in the ios appstore is a rocket and the icon for "apps" is 3 square sheets stacked in this kind of isometric view. This I think is supposed to be the app icon squircles stacked indicating "here be many apps"... If you can figure out that's what they are and not just squares. "Subscriptions" in the youtube app is 2 lines and a rectangle with the play icon inside. All of these I mentioned have a word below them describing the content type.

Comment: "but not that they are coming soon." @Joonas please simplify if possible.

Comment: To condense my point: Icons don't have to tell a story. They can convey an idea. Even a vague one. Context can often help. They can also be somewhat unrelated to the content. If you look at big websites or apps you'll find this is what they do very often. This might be dumbing it down a bit too much but the worst case scenario with icons is that if you can't find a perfect match, even an unrelated icon can work as a sort of graphical filler content or something akin to color coding. [So here's sort of my prior example in the form of an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imodS.png).

Comment: @Joonas thanks for clarification. I got your point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put cats and dogs and vaccines and princess Diana into an icon. You need something generic that covers the industry, not the various topics. Since most media is consumed online today, why not just show a newsfeed icon.

[image]

Comment: Those waves represent wi fi?

Comment: No, it just looks like a wi-fi but different. Google: RSS icon. Things derived from that, suggesting communication, which also means media ----- https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/rss-icon-flat-illustration-vector-260nw-1474228136.jpg

Comment: I'm gonna stick with your views :D

Comment: I tried but I just realized wikipedia page shows it's just tech and web stuff (some xml file format). So i wonder people will get it? Most will see it as wi fi i guess

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though "The Media" is pretty much about reporting events in one form or another-
So here is a (very) quick sketch of the first idea that comes to my mind.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let it be a generic TV news reader or a commentator with a microphone. Insert a snake tongue:

[image]

If it's an usual icon there's not much room even for this. But in bigger size you can also have treacherous eyes, big smiling mouth and a couple of long fangs.

Comment: Like in this example https://www.dropbox.com/s/3jjx6gcaaj0d6nj/3Hunt122.jpg?dl=0